# Update marker text google maps API

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

So i am using the Google maps API for my website and I want the markers text to be equal to the value of another html element. Anyone here knows how to update the value of the text property of a marker in the google maps API?

Here is my code regarding the problem.

```
var map, marker;
var input = document.getElementById('inputField');
input.onkeyup = function() {
    //want to set the marker.text property to input.value and update the markers text
}

function myMap() {
    var long = 59.614503;
    var lat = 16.539939;

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
    var mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(long, lat),
        zoom: 16,
        styles: [......]
    }
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(long, lat),
    label: {
        color: 'white',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: '10px',
        text: arena
    },
    optimized: false,
    visible: true,
    draggable: true,
});
marker.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the existing label object, set its `text` property to the desired value, then set it on the marker (unless you want to change other formatting).

```
input.onkeyup = function() {
  var label = marker.getLabel();
  label.text = input.value;
  marker.setLabel(label);
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ueLpd6j9/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map, marker;

function initialize() {
  var input = document.getElementById('inputField');
  input.onkeyup = function() {
    var label = marker.getLabel();
    console.log(label);
    label.text = input.value;
    marker.setLabel(label);
  }

  function myMap() {
    var lat = 59.614503;
    var lng = 16.539939;
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var mapProp = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
      zoom: 16
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
      label: {
        color: 'white',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: '10px',
        text: "arena"
      },
      optimized: false,
      visible: true,
      draggable: true,
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
  }
  myMap();
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#googleMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<input id="inputField" />
<div id="googleMap"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You coul try using

```
 marker.label.text = 'my_new_text';  // set the new text  
 marker.label..setStyles(); //  Force label to redraw (makes update visible)
```

Comment: Thanks `marker.label.text` fixed an issue where my labels were not updating correctly when using `marker.setLabel(label);`