# Dynamically change google map marker text when clicking a link

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have tried many ways to change the label text in the marker when clicking a link but getting no where.  I have the following code:

```
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
      center: {lat: 51.5078788, lng: -0.0877321},
      zoom: 16,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
```

I then create custom markers:

```
var icons = {
      main: {
        icon: 'marker.png'
      },
      locationone: {
        icon: 'marker-1.png'
      },
      locationtwo: {
        icon: 'marker-2.png'
      }
};
```

and set the features:

```
var features = [
      {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5078788, -0.0877321),
        type: 'main'
      }, {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5078788, -0.0877321),
        type: 'locationone',
        textone: 'default text',
        textwo: 'onclick replace with this text',
        texthree: 'onclick replace with this text'
      }, {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5078788, -0.0877321),
        type: 'locationtwo',
        textone: 'default text',
        textwo: 'onclick replace with this text',
        texthree: 'onclick replace with this text'
      }
};
```

I then plot them on the map:

```
var marker;
var i;

for (i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: features[i].position,
    icon: icons[features[i].type].icon,
    map: map,
    label: { color: '#ffffff', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: '14px', text: String(features[i].textone) }
   });
 };
```

I have three links:

```
<a href="#">Show the label for textone</a>
<a href="#">Show the label for textwo</a>
<a href="#">Show the label for texthree</a>
```

When I click on one of the above links, I would like it to the replace the label text.  Is this possible?  How would I do this?

Comment: It is possible.  Related questions: [Google map marker label text color change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41478502/google-map-marker-label-text-color-change), [Update marker text google maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49352317/update-marker-text-google-maps-api)

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  What I needed was to get a dom element to communicate with the map.  Your links above are using google's onclick events which is fine if I need to click the marker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 12 hours, I found the solution.  I hope this helps others. Using the onclick event, pass the marker and features but put your code in the return function otherwise the event will fire whether you click it or not.  Place the code below in the for loop under the marker function:

```
$(".class-on-ahref").click(function(marker, i){

             return function() {
             var label = marker.getLabel();
             label.text = String(features[i].textwo);
             marker.setLabel(label); 
          }

      }(marker, i));
```

Create an onclick event for each link.